# Printing variable in quotation marks C++

Tags: c++

given:

```
string element = "hello";
```

I would like to have the following printed:

```
"hello" //with quotation marks
```

I found how to print words with quotation marks using \"hello\", but I would like to use my variable name element to print out "hello".

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I made an edit to my post. I wanted to only use my variable name element to print out the content of the variable name in quotes.

Comment: The quotes aren't part of the string in the assignment. They let the **parser** know that you are entering a string. Either add escaped quotes as detailed in the other responses, or use raw strings.

Comment: Isn't that what @Brandon is doing?

Comment: Do you mean `std::cout << '"' << element << '"';`?

Comment: @drescherjm yes.

Comment: @Galik Yep, that's what the OP wants.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The closest you can get to have

```
string element = "hello";
std::cout << element
```

and have it print

```
"hello"
```

is to use [`std::quoted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted)  That would make the code

```
string element = "hello";
std::cout << std::quoted(element);
```

and it would output

```
"hello"
```

---

Do note that `std::quoted` does more then just add the out quotes.  If your string contains quotes then it will modify those and add a `\` in from of them.  That means

```
string element = "hello \"there\" bob";
std::cout << std::quoted(element);
```

will print

```
"hello \"there\" bob"
```

instead of

```
"hello "there" bob"
```

Comment: Upvoted because I've never heard of `std::quoted` before (!), but I'd argue that it just obscures the code relative to literal quotes in the string or `cout` call.

Comment: Thanks for the unique solution! This worked as well and I was not aware of a std::quoted.

Comment: @3Dave How does it obscure?  `std::cout << std::quoted(element);` self documents that you want to output to cout whatever is in `element` and have it be quoted.

Comment: `std::quoted()` was added in C++14.

Comment: @Dracep Your're welcome.  I was rather happy you asked this as it was my first time to be able to use it in an answer.

Comment: @Dracep Note that `quoted` does more than simply adding two `"`s. It also prints existing `"`s as `\"`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Good point.  I forgot about that.  I'll add that to the answer

Comment: Good to know. That Auto-escaping will eliminate more than a few lines of code in a few output file formats I have to support. Sadly not all. The code where that would be really nice has to compile under GCC 3.3.

Comment: Obscures because `std::quoted(foo)` is less obvious than literal quotes, even escaped, in the code. I don't disagree with your solution - it's readable, *but* less clear, IMHO. It's an observation, not a real complaint.

Comment: @user4581301 Not only that! You can `>>` into `std::quoted(x)`, and it will automatically unescape the string.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you for pointing that extra detail out. I actually wanted the \ in the string haha. Also is it possible to add the quotation in variable assignment instead of just printing out? Such as element = std::quoted(element);

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Just saw that. Was going to comment that alone will probably make a horde of CSV question answers obsolete.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Okay, that's just magic. (As in, magic that it's part of the STL. Next thing you know, we'll have Delphi-esque date parsing.) (As I go to research date parsing in C++14+...)

Comment: And the award for the quickest 100 points earned today goes to... :)

Comment: @Dracep *"is it possible to add the quotation in variable assignment"* You'll probably need a temporary `std::ostringstream` for that.

Answer (score 6):

use forward slash in front of quotation marks

```
std::cout << "\"" << element << "\"" << std::endl;
```

if you want to have quotation mark inside your string,
assign the variable with quotation mark with forward slash

```
string element = "\"hello\"";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like to only use the variable name element to print out "hello".

Comment: thanks so much! This worked and my problem was trying to implement the \ with the variable name.

Comment: @Dracep If it worked, then please click the checkbox next to this answer to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to write the quotation marks and the variable extra, like

```
std::cout << '\"' << element << '\"';
```

BTW: in contrast to a string literal like `"\""`, where you have to escape double quotes, by using a character literal, you can get away without escaping: So the following is valid as well:

```
std::cout << '"' << element << '"';
```

Comment: I think you want quotes, not newlines.

Comment: Do you have to escape double quotes if it's a char? (Guess I could go test it, but it seems counterintuitive)

Comment: @3Dave: you are right; both is valid. see edited answer

Answer (score 2):

```
string element = "\"hello\"";
std::cout << element;
```

Comment: I think he said he already knows how to make a string with quotes, but he wants to print quotes given a variable with the string.