# Use the " character in a string

Tags: c++, string, char, initialization, string-literals

Hello I would like to use the character "in a string variable like this:

```
std::string hello = """;
```

Is it possible to do such a thing or am I talking nonsense?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reading your C++ book or [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) is recommended in such cases.

Comment: duplicates: [Printing variable in quotation marks C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53110030/995714), [Include double-quote (") in C-string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20458489/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the escaped character  like

```
    std::string hello( "\"" );
```

or

```
    std::string hello = "\"";
```

or use a constructor that accepts a character literal like

```
std::string hello( 1, '"' );
```

Or you can use even a raw string literal like

```
std::string hello( R"(")" );
```

or

```
std::string hello = R"(")";
```

Answer (score 3):

Just escape it:

```
std::string hello = "\"";
```

Answer (score 3):

You have several ways, including:

- Escaping: `"\""`
- Raw string: `R"(")"` (since C++11)